# Invalid user login details error message in Android

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to make a message appears when the user enters the wrong username/password.

My code is working when the user enters the correct login details (it goes to the dashboard)
But I want an error message to appear saying "Invalid username/password" and then and "Ok" button, once the user click on the ok button, the login page get refreshed so that the user can enter the login details again.

**Please help me!!**

Thats my login.java

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener  {

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "***"; 
    private static final String URL = "***";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "login";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION =  NAMESPACE + "/" + METHOD_NAME; //in wsdl it's nothing

    EditText usersusername, userspassword;
    Button LB;



    @Override 


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login); 
         LB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
         LB.setOnClickListener(this);
         usersusername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editusername);
         userspassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpassword);




    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        if(usersusername.getText().length()==0) {
            usersusername.setError("Please enter your username");
        }
        if(userspassword.getText().length()==0) {
            userspassword.setError("Please enter your password");
        }
    switch (view.getId()){

    case R.id.loginbutton:
    new LongOperation().execute("");

    break;


    }
    }


    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{ 

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

           SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
           usersusername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editusername);
           userspassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpassword);
           String user_Name = usersusername.getText().toString();
           String user_Password = userspassword.getText().toString();


           PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
           unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
           unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
           unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
           request.addProperty("username",user_Name);//Pass properties to the variable
           //Using this to add parameters "username" grabbed from WSDL

           PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
           passwordProp.setName("password");
           passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
           passwordProp.setType(String.class);
           request.addProperty(passwordProp);




           SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); // Declare the version of the soap request
           envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

           try {
                HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);     
                aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); 
                SoapPrimitive result =(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse(); // the result will be a session ID
                String sessionid = result.toString(); // convert the session ID to a string so we can check if we got something or not
                //System.out.println( Something);
                if (sessionid != null ) 
                {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Dashboard.class);
                   intent.putExtra("username",usersusername.getText().toString());
                   startActivity(intent);
                }
                else 
                {      
                  Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Login.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
           }
           }
           catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();           }

            return null; 

        } // closing bracket of do in background
    } // closing bracket of long operation

}
```

and thats the error i get when i enter the WRONG login details

```
01-25 20:24:41.983: W/System.err(9311): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soapenv:Client' faultstring: 'Error - invalid login name' faultactor: '' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@4248fda8
01-25 20:24:41.983: W/System.err(9311):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:147)
01-25 20:24:41.993: W/System.err(9311):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
01-25 20:24:41.993: W/System.err(9311):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:118)
01-25 20:24:41.993: W/System.err(9311):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:275)
01-25 20:24:41.993: W/System.err(9311):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
01-25 20:24:41.993: W/System.err(9311):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:113)
01-25 20:24:41.993: W/System.err(9311):     at com.datacom.caservicedesk.Login$LongOperation.doInBackground(Login.java:120)
01-25 20:24:41.993: W/System.err(9311):     at com.datacom.caservicedesk.Login$LongOperation.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
01-25 20:24:41.993: W/System.err(9311):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-25 20:24:41.993: W/System.err(9311):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-25 20:24:41.993: W/System.err(9311):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-25 20:24:41.993: W/System.err(9311):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-25 20:24:41.993: W/System.err(9311):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask has also an `onPostExecute` callback which is called when `doInBackground` completes. So you should handle the result here and update the UI accordingly.

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{ 

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String param) {
            if(param == null) {
                // show dialog and prepare the fields for retry 
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!but can i create an alertDialog inside of onPostExecute ??